# confise when to release memory

Tags: iphone

i have created one view Controller(A) and this controller is using as a view in my app means i am adding view controllers view property to other view controller(B) view property. 
in this case should i release A or their view after adding to b ........??
or relese A controller in dealloc method ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding this view as subview of the parent view using `addSubview:` method and if you have some actions performed on the subview's view controller class I think it would be better to release it in `dealloc`. If you don't have any actions then it wont do any harm if you `release` it immediately. But I dont think that will be the case because if you have used view controller then it should contain some actions if not you could have chosen UIView instead. So I think releasing in `dealloc` is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Viewcontroller object in interface, you can release them only in Dealloc method.If you use local variable other view controller , you can release  viewcontroller object after adding to the master viewcontroller(it must be in interface).The style you use is in your hand..

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple ,

See in the declaration of your property if you have `retain` keyword then you must call `release` on it otherwise  NOT

Answer (score 0):

The better way is reales controller A in controller B's dealloc method.

Because, if you use controller A more than one time in controller B then reduce the crash chance and alloc dealloc method multiple time.